# Opencv: how to calculate the degrees(angles) of an object with its coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, arduino-uno

I am currently working on a project that combines motion detection with movement of a toy-gun in the (x,y) axes. I have managed to get the coordinates of the object's position (with the OpenCV proper commands) and sent them to Arduino in order to move the gun,but this did not work correctly. The code I am using is this:

```
#include <Servo.h>

#define servomaxx 114//max degree servo horizontal (x) can turn
#define servomaxy 120//max degree servo vertical (y) can turn
#define screenmaxx 480 //max screen horizontal (x) resolution
#define screenmaxy 320 //max screen vertical (y) resolution
#define servocenterx 90 //center position on (x)
#define servocentery 90 //center position on (y)
#define servopinx 9 //digital pin for servo x
#define servopiny 10 //digital pin for servo y
#define baudrate 9600 //com port speed. 
#define servorange 180

int x100byte;
int x010byte;
int x001byte;

int posx_taken=0;
int posy_taken=0;
int posx = 0;
int posy = 0;

Servo servox;
Servo servoy;


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);     
    pinMode(servopinx,OUTPUT);    
    pinMode(servopiny,OUTPUT);    
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

    servoy.attach(servopiny);
    servox.attach(servopinx);

    servox.write(servocenterx);
    delay(200);
    servoy.write(servocentery);
    delay(200);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 3) {
        x100byte = Serial.parseInt();
        delay(5);
        x010byte = Serial.parseInt();
        x001byte = Serial.parseInt();

        Serial.println("x100byte");
        Serial.println(x100byte);
        Serial.println("x010byte");
        Serial.println(x010byte);

        posx_taken=x100byte;
        posy_taken=x010byte;

        if ((posx_taken>screenmaxx) || (posy_taken>screenmaxy)) {
            Serial.println("Wrong number-too big values!");
        } else {
            if (posx_taken == screenmaxx) {
                posx = servomaxx;
            } else if (posx_taken == 0) {
                posx = 68;
            } else if (posx_taken == (screenmaxx / 2)) {
                posx=servorange / 2;
            } else {
                posx = ((posx_taken * 24) / (screenmaxx / 2)) + 66;
            }

            if (posy_taken == screenmaxy) {
              posy = 120;
            } else if (posy_taken == 0) {
              posy = 60;
            } else if (posy_taken == (screenmaxy / 2)){
              posy = 90;
            } else {
              posy = ((posy_taken * 30) / (screenmaxy / 2)) + 60;
            }
        }

        servox.write(posx);
        servoy.write(posy);  

        if (x001byte == 180) {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);  
            delay(1000);             
            digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have calculated the min and max degree of the vertical and horizontal movement of each servo, according to the horizontal and vertical camera angles (45o V, 58o H). In this case, the horizontal servo's (x) min value is 66 degrees and the max value is 112 degrees. Also, the vertical servo's (y)  min value is 60 degrees and the max value is 120 degrees.

At this point I would like to ask if there is a formula which converts the object's coordinates to degrees based on the camera's angle. The code above does not turn the gun at the correct point. Could anyone please help me?

I am using both an ASUS Xtion Pro Live camera(45o V, 58o H, 70o D) and a USB camera.

Comment: Please, format your code properly (as in a sensible, consistent manner). Get rid of all the magic numbers. Refactor the code to make smaller functions with single responsibility, eliminate repetition, etc. -- especially so that you can write some tests for the calculations. Also minimize the number of global variables, a number of them are unnecessary. | Honestly, and sorry if this sounds harsh, seeing that code and the question together with the word "gun" is quite scary.

Comment: I will make the changes and thank you for the suggestion @DanMašek. Don't be scared, it's only a toy. I am trying to make a sentry gun as the "project sentry gun (http://projectsentrygun.rudolphlabs.com/)" suggests  with opencv code and Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using some simple trigonometry.

To begin, let's make the assumption that any distortion due to optics has been eliminated and that the image center corresponds with the optical center. We can treat each plane (horizontal and vertical) independently to simplify the problem.

We can treat the image as a perspective projection. Looking from above (i.e. considering the horizontal plane only), it looks something like this:

[image]

The width of the image is known (480 pixels according to your code), as well as the angle α (half the horizontal FOV which you say is 58°).

Hence:

> a = w / 2 = 480 / 2 = 240 pixels
>
> α = 58° / 2 = 29°

Based on trigonometry, we have the following equations:

> tan(α) = a / d
>
> tan(β) = b / d

which is equivalent to

> d = a / tan(α)
>
> d = b / tan(β)

Taking `d` as common, we can then write

> a / tan(α) = b / tan(β)

which is equivalent to

> a * tan(β) = b * tan(α)

giving us

> tan(β) = b * tan(α) / a

and finally

> β = arctan(b * tan(α) / a)

---

Now we can substitute our known constants into this equation:

> β = arctan(b * tan(29°) / 240)

Since the angle α is constant, so will be its tangent. It may be more convenient to express this as

> K = tan(29°) / 240
>
> β = arctan(b * K)

---

Now, you might not want to actually calculate this on the AVR. A more flexible way may be to use a lookup table (one for each axis), which will map pixel position to angle (or even better target value for the servo).

You could either have it as a static array in the program memory, or if you have the space for it, keep it in SRAM, and allow uploading new LUTs through the serial port.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! One question please, in the last equation (β = arctan(b * K)), b stands of the object's coordinate on the (x) axis?

Comment: It would be the offset along the x axis from the image center.